# HttpServletResponse make url a forward slash(/) become two forward slash(//)

Tags: java, http, spring-mvc, servlets

the url in html:

```
<a href=""////jrdc.xxx.com/dh/nc?camp=19&mid=19&mat=121&unit=-&uuid=386931bea19dbba0e8f8c3291743d004a71669b5807d3eb49e150e08fcd93c83&aid=12&day=1493864666856&to=https://sale.xxx.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html" target="_blank">
```

the contronller:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
public void clickLog(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    try {
        // 
        String targetUrl = request.getParameter("to");         
       if(targetUrl != null && !targetUrl.contains("http")){
           targetUrl = "http://" + targetUrl;
       }
       response.sendRedirect(targetUrl);
    }catch (Exception e){

    }finally {

    }

}
```

the targetUrl to response.sendRedirect() is :

https://sale.jd.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html

the question is when redirect:
the url in chrome browser becomes:

```
https://sale.xxx.com//act//UuzWBLwPKX.html
```

which the "/" before "act" becomes "//", I don't want this result, why becomes this and how to become https://sale.xxx.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself; sorry for leaving out info, the project has a Filter to deal the request for defending XSS attack

```
public class FHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper{

     public FHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
        }
     @Override
     public String getParameter(String name) {
        return escapeXss(super.getParameter(escapeXss(name)));
     }
    protected String escapeXss(String param) {
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(param)) {
           return 
     StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(param));
    }
    return param;
}
..
}
```

so the String "to=https://sale.xxx.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html",
in Java:"https://sale.xxx.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html"
so the solution is :

```
 String targetUrl = request.getParameter("to");
 targetUrl = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(targetUrl);
if(targetUrl != null && !targetUrl.contains("http")){
....
}
```

Comment: bug I still do not konw why becomes “//act”

Answer (score -1):

Use [URI Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to resolve this problem

```
URI uri = new URI(targetUrl).normalize();
System.out.println("Target URL ----> "+uri.toString());
```

Result:

```
Target URL ----> https://sale.xxx.com/act/UuzWBLwPKX.html
```